# Vue Component does not render changes of object (despite $set being used)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-reactivity

I am trying to build a Vue component that displays the hour and minute of a `Date` and emits a changed version when a + or - button is pressed.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/knwUn.png
(not enough reputation to post image)

Using the Vue.js Devtools (in Google Chrome) I observed that:

- The change event fires and contains a correct date
- The `date` prop was updated correctly

It just does not rerender the date.

https://jsfiddle.net/JoshuaKo/6c73b2gt/2

```html
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <time-input :date="meeting.startDate"
                @change="$set(meeting, 'startDate', $event)"
                ></time-input>
    <p>
      {{meeting.startDate.toLocaleString()}}
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

```
Vue.component('time-input', {
  props: {
    date: Date,
    minuteSteps: {
      type: Number,
      default: 1
    }
  },
  methods: {
    increaseTime: function() {
      if (!this.date) return
      const newDate = this.date
      newDate.setMinutes(this.date.getMinutes() + this.minuteSteps)
      this.$emit('change', newDate)
    },
    decreaseTime: function() {
      if (!this.date) return
      const newDate = this.date
      newDate.setMinutes(this.date.getMinutes() - this.minuteSteps)
      this.$emit('change', newDate)
    },
    time: function() {
      if (!this.date) return '??:??'
      const h = this.date.getHours().toString()
      const m = this.date.getMinutes().toString()
      return _.padStart(h, 2, '0') + ':' + _.padStart(m, 2, '0')
    }
  },
  computed: {
  },
  template: `
<div class="time">
  <button :disabled="!date" class="control" @click="decreaseTime">-</button>
  <span>{{time()}}</span>
  <button :disabled="!date" class="control" @click="increaseTime">+</button>
</div>
  `.trim()
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    meeting: {
      name: 'test meeting',
      startDate: new Date(),
      endDate: null
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object in `meeting.startDate` is always the same, so it doesn't trigger anything.

You should create a new Date object each time, so change the lines:

```
const newDate = this.date
```

to:

```
const newDate = new Date(this.date.getTime())
```

Also, the `$set` (alias of `Vue.set`) is intended to add properties that must be reactive. As no propperty is added (just modified), you don't need it here.

Comment: It does work, but I do not understand why.
On the @change event I change `meeting.startDate` which is passed as a prop to <time-input>. Could you explain "The object in `meeting.startDate` is always the same, so it doesn't trigger anything." in more detail?

Comment: A variable contains a reference to an Object, so if you change the object, the variable does not change, and you were assigning always the same object. As you work always on the same object, you could also have set the event this way: `@change="$forceUpdate()"`. This instruction forces Vue to update the layout, as if some change was done.